# Minor vote-to-close bug when one voter is promoted to moderator

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

Check out [this interesting closed question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/44/73); my name appears twice. I voted to close before made moderator pro tempore, and again afterwards, and my name appears in the list twice because of that. It's a very minor bug which admittedly will happen pretty rarely, but it should at least be on the bug report list.

Comment: Well... You did vote twice, even though the second time wasn't really a "vote".

Comment: "eykanal" - a vote so nice, he used it twice :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't really a bug, as Shog9 notes - you literally *did* vote twice. This is acceptable because we're not going to go back and undo all close votes of a user when they are promoted to moderator.

Consequent to that, a moderator's ability is not to vote to close, but to simply close - this is thus unrelated to whether or not you had voted on the question in the past. It's not as if your vote "counted twice" because you already could close it in one shot to begin with.

While it does come across as amusing behavior, I'm of the expectation that this isn't something that truly needs to be changed because it is non-impactful and also, as you note, relatively rare in occurrence.

Comment: Makes sense, just wanted to report it in any event as it just looks kinda awkward.

Comment: There's no harm in having reported this. ♪ It *does* look awkward, but ultimately I would call this "expected behavior" in terms of why it looks that way.

Comment: Maybe it would be less 'confusing' if the moderator symbol wasn't present for the non-mod vote. Though this would incur expense of the logic to do so, so again, perhaps not fix-worthy.

Comment: For the non mod user it looks like cheating. I don’t like it.